# prevent google fabric from changing build version code timestamp

Tags: google-fabric, crashlytics-beta

I want my Android versionCode to === my iOS CFBundleVersion but Crashlytics Beta restamps them upon upload which gums up other parts of our overall process. Can I disable that "feature" somehow?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Can you share more about what changes you're seeing to that value and when it's happening?

Comment: Thank you Mike - I can't repro when I look on Fabric now. Apologies I got this wrong.